# A ship captain sails 500 miles due south and then 1,200 miles due east

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the minimum number of miles the captain must sail to return to his original position?

I got $\sqrt{500^2+1200^2}=1300$

The practice test I'm taking says the answer can't be determined which I'm $99.9\%$ sure is wrong but just want to double check.

Comment: Imagine starting 500 miles north of the south pole. Then when you try to go east, you don't end up moving anywhere so you are only 500 miles away from the start.

Comment: But the problem doesn't say anything about South Pole

Comment: @MattB If the problem says  the ship traveled 1,200 (or 3) kms due east then the scenario you're describing cannot be. Yet the idea is correct, and beginning at the **north pole** gives a distance less than $\;1,300\;$ ...in fact, much less.

Comment: This seems like a GRE Quantitative Comparison question. It would be easier to find the answer by eliminating the wrong ones.

Comment: The starting point is not given, so take the minimum over all possible starting points. From some points, the journey is impossible. Matt B's one can be modified to start a bit further away from the South Pole, so that 1200 miles due east ends up being an exact number of circuits (so this gives an actual 1200 mile trip). Similarly starting at the North Pole gives 500 miles from start.

Comment: @Galc127 What? It is **given** the ship went due south and then due east. There are no "different paths" here if we keep the directions exact. What could be, and is in fact, is that different starting points can give different answers.

Comment: @Galc127 In fact it asks about the **minimal** path back to the starting point. So what?

Comment: @DonAntonio, I understood the question incorrectly.

Comment: @Fib1123 That is exactly what it is.  The actual question asked which number is greater between 1350 and the minimum number of miles to return to original position.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Then, as has been already comment and answered, the correct answer must be $\;1,350 \;$ miles .

Comment: @DonAntonio I can understand that the answer can't be determined based on the curvature of the earth but how do you break from that to say the answer *is* 1350?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Because $\;1,350\;$ is *larger* than **any** other *minimal* such distance, no matter where the starting point is. I thought this was already clear...

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh right you mean the answer of which is greater.  Sorry I had a brain fart. Yes that's the answer I selected and was surprised for it to tell me that "this can't be determined"

Comment: Dean, I think you need to give us the _exact wording_ of this question, to stop us all going round in circles. Please edit it into your question, rather than posting it as a comment.

Comment: @TonyK Sorry I've already skipped past the question so I don't have easy access to it anymore.  It's probably best treat the question as-is or I can delete it.

Comment: @TonyK Here seems to be the original question: http://gre.kmf.com/question/1924.html ...and by the way the answer given there is A: the quantity 1,350 miles is greater...as it should be, of course. Also here and with the same answer: http://www.maintests.com/gre/quantitative-comparisons/question-572.html

Comment: Well done @DonAntonio! So the OP's question is flawed. (But don't delete it, Dean -- edit it.)

Comment: @DonAntonio Nice find.  I guess the site I'm on did a bad job of copying since they had the wrong answer and also omitted the explanation.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I found a site where they ask about this very question and somebody there says the given answer is D...but then other tell them that cannot be.

Answer (score 2):

Say you begin exactly at the north pole, then travel 500 km. due south. Now, **any** distance you travel due east or west leaves you at exactly 500 kms. from the north pole...so the answer depends on what point on Earth you started your trip at and thus cannot be determined.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is right. If this problem is given to many people 99.9% have the same answer. And if in practice set answer is not same as you calculated. Its exception.

Comment: The answer is never right, wherever the ship starts from, because the earth is not flat. It doesn't matter what 99.9% of people say $-$ the correct answer is 500 miles.

Comment: @TonyK I think that's correct but not the reason you give: the distances are measured *on the surface of the Earth* and thus the minimal distances, larger distances and etc. are measured the same way. Of course, there can be discrepancies as for the curvature of our very non-flat...and very non-completely-round planet, but everywhere the assumption is the distances are taken straightly. Just like trying to argue the sum of the angles of a triangle are not **actually** $\;180^\circ\;$ because there doesn't exist completely plane triangles...too much, imo.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Nobody is assuming or implying that these distances should be measured as the Euclidean distance between points in $\mathbb R^3$. The verb 'sail' is used, which means that of course distances are measured along the surface. So I don't really understand your comment.

Comment: I am not enough experienced like you. But I bet if we give this type of question here 99% people gave us answer 1300. Because in question it is not clear that earth is flat or not and from which direction he start.

Comment: I see your confidence has decreased significantly!

Comment: Its not the case of debate its the case of thinking. We have questions in which rivers and hills given but still we ignore whether rocks and trees in the way. All depend on question if nothing give except some distances. We can't assume other things.

Comment: I think the point of this question was to realize that places like the North Pole exist on the Earth for which the answer is not "the usual one" many would come up with using Pythagoras There and stuff. Just my opinion.

Comment: Yes I agree. But in some cases its not possible to think this. Just my opinion.